# How are some planets not spheres?

Tags: voltron-legendary-defender

Voltron Legendary Defender Season 2 shows us several planets.  However, two prominent planets shown are not spherical.   S02e02 22:28 and s02e07 6:36 show us the mermaid planet and Black Lion's home planet, respectively.

How/why are these planets not spherical?  Wouldn't the atmosphere fall off of the Black Lion's "planet"?

[image: Mermaid Planet]

[image: Black Lion's home planet]